# Getting root id in Google Drive Api v3 in C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to find the root folder id in Google Drive Api v3

In Google Drive Api v2 has a direct way t get the root folder ID:

```
string rootFolderID = (ServiceV2.About.Get().Execute()).RootFolderId;
```

How can I find the root id in v3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this answer?

[The official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder) says as follows.

> You can use the alias root to refer to the root folder anywhere a file ID is provided

So you can use `root` as the root folder ID.

#### Note:

- If you need to retrieve the actual root folder ID instead of `root`, how about using files.get method?

  - `service.Files.Get("root").Execute()`
  - By this, you can retrieve the actual root folder ID.

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for. Thank's a lot!

Comment: @Julian Docev Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Tanaike you seem to know well google drive sdk. I have posted another question. Can you please see if you can help me with any solution or idea. Thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243662/google-drive-api-stream-large-files-25mb