# Google Drive Api Stream large files (>25MB)

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm having a web app and I want to stream a large video file from google drive in html5 video tag.

I have tried with a direct link. Something like this:

"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=&id=" + id;

It works for small files but for files larger than 25mb there is a virus scan and I can't bypass it.
I know that I can download it and stream it from a server but I want to know if there is a way to stream it directly from google drive without having a copy on my server.

Does anyone knows a way or have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: For example, how about using OAuth2 and/or Service Account? And if the file can be publicly shared, how about using API key? When those are used, the file can be downloaded by Drive API. But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want. So if you want to use other methods, I apologize.

Comment: Yes. I'm using OAth2. I can download a file on chuncks too. But i want to be able to stream this file in HTML5. If the file is less than 25 mb google drive let's you do that. You don't need to have the file publicly shared, because you have all the Oath2 credentials to work with that file. So google generate a download link for me which I put in  src attribute of a video tag in html and it works fine. But when the file is biger than 25 mb, the download link asks you to confirme with yes or now and that is the problem.

Comment: Can you provide the sample endpoint for downloading file? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I tried to say yes and continue programaticaly with javascript, but ofcourse there is a CORS policy that block's it. I can download the file on chuncks and stream it on my own from the server, but I'm looking for a way to do that directly from google drive, without the need of having a copy of that file on my server.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: Thank' for trying Tanaike. If you come up with un idea i will be happy to hear it. Up to now the best silution i have came up is to download it on chuncks on the server and while downloading it give the file location from the server as a src in the video html5 tag. It works but it will be better if i can download it directly on client side. So i'm looking more for that kind of a solution.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Comment: Martin Zeitler. I'm familiar with that part of the documentation. M'i missing something. Can you be more speciffic?